# AES encryption from main, decryption from child

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes, parent-child

I have a main and a child process. I created an encrypted string with a key in main using openssl library. I am also created an encrypted string with the same key. Both input values are same but their results are different.

Here is my main process encryption:

```
unsigned char *encryptedString;
unsigned char key[8] = {4,1,8,9,1,61,64,220};
unsigned char * enc_out = malloc(80*sizeof(char));

AES_KEY enc_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
AES_encrypt(originalString, enc_out, &enc_key);

encryptedString = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
strcpy(encryptedString, enc_out);

free(enc_out);
```

Here is my child decryption process

```
//gets encryptedString as parameter argv[2] from main and it is ok

//gets originalString as argv[1] from main and it is ok

//minkeyspace and maxkeyspace calculated and they are ok


unsigned char *encryptedString;
AES_KEY dec_key;
unsigned char key[8] = {4,1,8,9,1,61,64, 0};
unsigned char * dec_out = malloc(80*sizeof(char));

for(j = minkeyspace; j < maxkeyspace ; j++){
    key[7] = j;

    AES_set_decrypt_key(key,128,&dec_key);
    AES_decrypt(encryptedString, dec_out, &dec_key);

if(strcmp(originalString, dec_out) == 0){ //They are not equal. There is a problem
    puts("FOUND");
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned char key[8] = {4,1,8,9,1,61,64,220};
unsigned char * enc_out = malloc(80*sizeof(char));

AES_KEY enc_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(key, 128, &enc_key);
```

You are using 128-bit keys, but only specify the first 64 bits (8 bytes).  The next (32 or 64) bits are the value returned by malloc, which will be different every time.  Thus, you are using different keys for encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `dec_out` should not be equal to `encryptedString`, it should be equal to `originalString`.

Also, when looking at the edited code( I guess I missed it before ), you use different keys for encryption/decryption:

```
unsigned char key[8] = {4,1,8,9,1,61,64,220};
unsigned char key[8] = {4,1,8,9,1,61,64, 0};
```

One last thing. Sinch you don't initialize the data ( dec_out, encrypted_string ) and since AES_encrypt / AES_decrypt only process one [block at a time](http://securestorage.sourceforge.net/doc/ss-util_8h.html#a23), you get different (not defined which ) bytes after the block and so `strcmp` fails, try comparing the first blocks using `memcmp`.

Comment: i am trying to create the key. I am editing the last element of the key.

Comment: it looks like their lengths are not equal...when i expecting them to be equeal in j= 220, their difference is 94.

Comment: each time i run the main..diffence changes.

Comment: read the last edit, and remember to compare only the first block and not with strcmp.